# Automatically copy every file that appers in a certain folder

Tags: batch-file, automation

I save all files I need for my work (word docs, excel sheets, zip archives, etc) to a certain folder. After I'm done with those files I delete them. But sometimes I need to look something up in an old document that I deleted. So I need to save all the files from my work folder to another automatically. Like backup. Can someone help me with a scipt?

P.S. I get tons of documents in a day, so it takes much time to save them all manually. I could run a script to do that for me. Plus the scipt must save file as soon as they appear in the folder.

Comment: but what if a new file has the same name. What if u edit the file?

Comment: yes, a new file can have the same name. But I don't need to save edited files

Answer (score 0):

I created this batch script for incremental and scheduled backup using xcopy command in batch.

The first execution of this script is to configure the paths of the source and the destination. And saves them in a .cfg file and then makes a full copy for the first time.

It creates a scheduled task to run every hour with an incremental copy (ie : only copies the new files or has been modified from the source)

So, you can give a try for this batch script : ***Incremental_Backup.bat***

```bat
@echo off
:: Incremental_Backup.bat Created by Hackoo on 12/08/2017
:: It is a total copy first and then incrementally,
:: ie, it just copies the new files and changed files.
:: Create a Schedule Task for Copying files Hourly
Mode con cols=95 lines=5 & color 0E
Title %~nx0 for Incremental Backup with XCopy Command by Hackoo 2017
set "Settings=%~dpn0_Settings.cfg"
Set "FirstFull_CopyLog=%~dpn0_FirstFull_CopyLog.txt"
Set "LogFile=%~dpn0_Incremental_CopyLog.txt"
Set "TaskName=Backup_Task"
Rem The repeated task is in minutes (60 min = 1 hour)
Set "Repeat_Task=60"
If not exist "%Settings%" (
    Call :BrowseForFolder "Please choose the source folder for the backup" SourceFolder
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    If defined SourceFolder (
        echo(
        echo             You chose "!SourceFolder!" as source folder
    ) else (
        echo(
        Color 0C & echo                    The source folder is not defined ... Exiting ......
        Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul & exit
    )
    Call :BrowseForFolder "Please choose the target folder for the backup" TargetFolder
    If defined TargetFolder (
        echo(
        echo             You chose "!TargetFolder!" as Target folder
    ) else (
        echo(
        Color 0C & echo                    The Target folder is not defined ... Exiting ......
        Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul & exit
    )
Timeout /T 3 /nobreak>nul
    (
        echo "!SourceFolder!" 
        echo "!TargetFolder!\Backups_%ComputerName%\" 
    )> "%Settings%"
cls & echo( & echo(
echo         Please wait a while ... The Backup to "!TargetFolder!\Backups_%ComputerName%\" is in progress... 
Call :Backup_XCopy "!SourceFolder!" "!TargetFolder!\Backups_%ComputerName%\" "!FirstFull_CopyLog!"
Timeout /T 1 /nobreak>nul 
Call :Create_Schedule_Task_Copy %Repeat_Task% %TaskName%
Start "" "!FirstFull_CopyLog!" & exit
) else (
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%Settings%"') do (
    set /a idx+=1
    set Param[!idx!]=%%a
)

Set "SourceFolder=!Param[1]!"
Set "TargetFolder=!Param[2]!"

Cls & echo( & echo(
echo       Please wait a while ... The Backup to !TargetFolder! is in progress... 
Call :Backup_XCopy !SourceFolder! !TargetFolder! !LogFile!
Rem Just to query the Backup_Task and log it
    (
        echo(
        echo %Date% @ %Time%
        echo( 
        echo ======================================== ====================== ===============
        @for /f "skip=2 delims=" %%a in ('Schtasks /Query /TN %TaskName%') do (
            @echo %%a
        )
        echo ======================================== ====================== ===============
    )>> !LogFile!
)
Timeout /T 1 /nobreak>nul 
Exit
::****************************************************************************
:BrowseForFolder
set "psCommand="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application')^
.BrowseForFolder(0,'%1',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell %psCommand%`) do set "%2=%%I"
exit /b
::****************************************************************************
:Backup_XCopy <Source> <Target> <LogFile>
Xcopy /I /D /Y /S /E /J /C /F %1 %2 > %3 2>&1
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************
:Create_Schedule_Task_Copy <Repeat_Task_Every(N)Minute> <TaskName>
(
    Schtasks /create /SC minute /MO %1 /TN "%2" /TR "%~f0" 
    Schtasks /Query /TN "%2" 
)>> "!FirstFull_CopyLog!" 2>&1
exit /b
::****************************************************************************
```